# Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'xxxx' was successfully initialized, but failed to start

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I installed Neo4j community version yesterday on Windows 10, but when I use Spring to manipulate a new Neo4j database, everything is ok .But  when I open the database by browser, and open by Spring later, the database faild to start. the error info is like this

`Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@79fcd194' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Neo4j cannot be started because the database files require upgrading and upgrades are disabled in the configuration. Please set 'dbms.allow_upgrade' to 'true' in your configuration file and try again.".`

however, I had set the dbms.allow_upgrade to true, but did no function.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which version of Neo4j community? Did you have an earlier version of the database or does this happen with a brand new database ?

Comment: Just a question before removing the spring-data-neo4j tag: are you also using the compatible versions of the neo4j-server dependency in your application? Also when using the embedded version, did you set the config parameter also there?

Comment: the version of Neo4j community is 3.5.30，and it is my first time to use Neo4j.  the dependency in my application is like <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId><artifactId>neo4j</artifactId> <version>3.3.5</version>, and set no config